# Poor performance of many if-else statements in Java

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a method that checks all of the combinations of 5 different conditions with 32 if-else statements (think of the truth table). The 5 different letters represent methods that each run their own regular expressions on a string, and return a boolean indicating whether or not the string matches the regex. For example:

```
if(A,B,C,D,E){

}else if(A,B,C,D,!E){

}else if(A,B,C,!D,!E){

}...etc,etc.
```

However, it is really affecting the performance of my application (sorry, I can't go into too many details). Can anyone recommend a better way to handle such logic?

Each method using a regular expression looks like this:

```
String re1 = "regex here";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
return m.find();
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you'd show us something other than pseudo-code... for example, do you actually evaluate all the conditions each time, or do you evaluate them once and only check the combinations?

Comment: I added how I handle the regex for each method, does that help?

Comment: I bet A, B, C... are all functions that they significant file to evaluate... keep the result in local booleans. Edit (for the edit), so you evaulate regexp (that are slow to boot each time/ multiple times)

Comment: @littleK: Not really - because your `if` code is still not valid Java...

Comment: Are you able to share the Pattern instance among the methods?

Comment: Just to be clear: your A, B, C, D, E are booleans that you evaluate once?   You are not reevaluating the regexs for each `if`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try

```
boolean a,b,c,d,e;
int combination = (a?16:0) + (b?8:0) + (c?4:0) + (d?2:0) + (e?1:0);
switch(combination) {
   case 0:
        break;
   // through to
   case 31:
        break;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked great for me, and really improved the performance. I should have realized my design was poor from the beginning! Thanks again.

Comment: A heads-up: natively, this is still a series of "if / else" statements. It ends up being faster because the compiler will optimize it into a "jump table". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Compilation and the related links ("branch table") to understand a little bit more about how a switch statement can be done in constant time.

Comment: @JeffFerland 'natively this is still a series of "if/else" statements is meaningless. "Natively", if that means anything, is what it compiles to, which as you go on to say correctly is a branch table.

Comment: @EJP with no compiler optimization as when using something that isn't an integer / enum, or if the compiler just doesn't like you, it will be a series of tests rather than jumps.

Comment: @JeffFerland Depends on the compiler for a start, but in any case that's a long way from 'natively it *is still* a series of if/else statements'. Especially as the language in question is Java.

Comment: @EJP well, any way you look at it, we both agree the answer given is right. I was just trying to spread a little knowledge about why it was faster.

Comment: @JeffFerland Sure, good solution. No obfuscation required ;-)

Comment: how much faster is it than if-else?

Answer (score 8):

represent each condition as a bit flag, test each condition once, and set the relevant flag in a single int.  then switch on the int value.

```
int result = 0;
if(A) {
  result |= 1;
}
if(B) {
  result |= 2;
}
// ...

switch(result) {
  case 0: // (!A,!B,!C,!D,!E)
  case 1: // (A,!B,!C,!D,!E)
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**All the above answers are wrong, because the correct answer to an optimisation question is: Measure!**  Use a profiler to measure where your code is spending its time.

Having said that, I'd be prepared to bet that the biggest win is avoiding compiling the regexes more than once each.  And after that, as others suggested, only evaluate each condition once and store the results in boolean variables.  So thait84 has the best answer.

I'm also prepared to bet jtahlborn and Peter Lawrey's and Salvatore Previti suggestions (essentially the same), clever though they are, will get you negligible additional benefit, unless you're running on a 6502...

(This answer reads like I'm full of it, so in the interests of full disclosure I should mention that I'm actually hopeless at optimisation. But measuring still is the right answer.)

Comment: *"All the above answers are wrong, because the correct answer to an optimisation question is: Measure!"*

You could apply that to anything. I'd say it's not applicable when the person asking the question is looking for another method to measure...

Comment: What, you'd say it's not applicable to measure a performance problem before trying to correct it?  Are you sure?

Comment: On reflection, the OP did explicitly ask for improvements to his code, and I didn't answer that.  Maybe I should have just commented his question.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more details, it might be helpful to arrange the if statements in such a way that the ones which do the "heavy" lifting are executed last.  This is making the assumption that the other conditionals will be true thereby avoiding the "heavy" lifting ones all together.  In short, take advantage of short-circuits if possible.

Comment: I do plan to use your suggestion. I'll be interested to see what kind of performance gain I can see. Still, I think I'll need to do more.

Answer (score 2):

Run the regex once for each string and store the results in to booleans and just do the if / else on the booleans instead of running the regex multiple times.  Also, if you can, try to re-use a pre-compiled version of your regex and re-use this.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution: use a switch creating a binary value.

```
int value = (a ? 1 : 0) | (b ? 2 : 0) | (c ? 4 : 0) | (d ? 8 : 0) | (e ? 16 : 0);

switch (value)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    ...
    case 31:
}
```

If you can avoid the switch and use an array it would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe partition it into layers, like so:

```
if(A) {
    if(B) {
        //... the rest
    } else {
        //... the rest
    }
} else {
    if(B) {
        //... the rest
    } else {
        //... the rest
    }
}
```

Still, feels like there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution with EnumSet.  However it's too verbose and I guess I prefer @Peter Lawrey's solution.

In Effective Java by Bloch it's recommended to use EnumSet over bit fields, but I would make an exception here.  Nonetheless I posted my solution because it could be useful for someone with a slightly different problem.

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

public enum MatchingRegex {
  Tall, Blue, Hairy;

  public static EnumSet<MatchingRegex> findValidConditions(String stringToMatch) {
     EnumSet<MatchingRegex> validConditions = EnumSet.noneOf(MatchingRegex.class);
     if (... check regex stringToMatch for Tall)
       validConditions.add(Tall);
     if (... check regex stringToMatch for Blue)
       validConditions.add(Blue);
     if (... check regex stringToMatch for Hairy)
       validConditions.add(Hairy);
     return validConditions;         
  }
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
Set<MatchingRegex> validConditions = MatchingRegex.findValidConditions(stringToMatch);

if (validConditions.equals(EnumSet.of(MatchingRegex.Tall, MathchingRegex.Blue, MatchingRegex.Hairy))
   ...
else if (validConditions.equals(EnumSet.of(MatchingRegex.Tall, MathchingRegex.Blue))
   ...
else if ... all 8 conditions like this
```

But it would be more efficient like this:

```
if (validConditions.contains(MatchingRegex.Tall)) {
  if (validConditions.contains(MatchingRegex.Blue)) {
     if (validConditions.contains(MatchingRegex.Hairy)) 
        ... // tall blue hairy
     else
        ... // tall blue (not hairy)
  } else {
     if (validConditions.contains(MatchingRegex.Hairy)) 
        ... // tall (not blue) hairy
     else
        ... // tall (not blue) (not hairy)
} else {
      ... remaining 4 conditions
}
```

Comment: +1 I think this solution is easier to understand and modify(without making a mistake)

Comment: This could be *surely* made much shorter, more readable and faster by replacing the `EnumSet` by four booleans. -1 for using them, +1 for using nested conditions (which is possibly as fast as the `switch` and more readable).

Answer (score 0):

You could also adapt your if/else to a switch/case (which I understand is faster)

Answer (score 0):

pre-generating A,B,C,D and E as booleans rather than evaluating them in `if` conditions blocks would provide both readability and performance. If you're also concerned about performance the different cases, you may organise them as a tree or combine them into a single integer (X = (A?1:0)|(B?2:0)|...|(E?16:0)) that you'd use in a `switch`.